# группировка pandas и выбор нужных значений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет!
Мне нужно сгруппировать мой dataframe по некому id и для каждого получить в результате одну строчку, в столбцах которой будут последние по timestamp-столбцу ненулевые значения и первое значение для столбца timestamp
То есть если у меня:

```
id,timestamp,status,value
1,12:00,ok,null
1,13:00,null,3
1,14:00,null,4
2,12:00,error,null
2,13:00,null,1
```

в итоге я должна получить

```
id,timestamp,status,value
1,12:00,ok,4
```

Как это можно сделать?
Хотелось бы не очень костыльно и медленно, потому что данные большие, но кроме чего-то типа

```
tmp.status[tmp.status.isna()] = tmp.groupby([key], sort=False)['status'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
```

ничего на ум не приходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь можно сделать?

Comment: вы не могли бы привести пример исходного фрейма?

Comment: @strawdog он выглядит как я описала:  id,timestamp,status,value - это как раз он)
сейчас поправлю чтобы было понятнее)

Comment: вопрос не в том, как он выглядит, а в том, с чем нам работать. необходимо предоставлять пример данных, чтобы отвечающему не пришлось самому его выдумывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При df:

```
   id timestamp status  value
0   1     12:00     ok    NaN
1   1     13:00    NaN    3.0
2   1     14:00    NaN    4.0
```

можно сделать аггрегацию. для примера:

```
res = df.groupby("id").agg({"timestamp":"first", "value":"last"})
```

res:

```
   timestamp  value
id                 
1      12:00    4.0
```

Comment: спасибо! думаю это то, что нужно